# BUG with my Double to String function in C

Tags: c

I have a little problem with my **C** code. I need to create a function which converts a **Double** to a **String**.

**My prototype:**
 `void Double2String(char *output,double val,int n);`

***output**: Array output

**val**: Value to convert

**n**: Amount of digit after the dot (***BUG***)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void Double2String(char *output,double val,int n);

int main() {
    char output[100] = {0};
    Double2String(&output,M_PI,3);
    printf("PI=%s\n",output);
    return 0;
}

void Double2String(char *output,double val,int n){
    sprintf(&*output,"%%0.%df",n); //Create the format "%0.nf"
    sprintf(&*output,&*output,val);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
n=2 => PI=3.14 | n=3 => PI=3.142| n=4 => PI=3.14166 | n=5 => PI=3.1415959 |...
```

So after n=3 my format bug and add more digit like n=4+1 n=5+2 n=6+3.

Comment: Using the same buffer for format and output isn’t going to work

Comment: What's the point of `&*output`? Why not simply `output`?

Comment: Because without this my code don't work.

Comment: Also remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So if you have `char output[100];` then using plain `output` is equal to `&output[0]` which will be of type `char *`. But `&output` is a pointer to the array itself, and will have the type `char (*) [100]`, which is not the same as the expected `char *`.

Comment: @MikeVine My objective is to do it with one line and I want to use can of var.

Comment: Possibly the error: `sprintf(&*output,&*output,val)`. You're not allowed to use the same string as both source and destination for `sprintf`, that leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Belaying the sanity fo `&*output`, which is completely worthless, `sprintf(&*output,&*output,val);` is a recipe for for madness.

Comment: yes is that. I have created another arrays that store the format and it's work.

Comment: Then... do that?

Comment: @WhozCraig How to do it in one line of code ?

Comment: You mean `sprintf(output, "%0.*f", val, n);` ? I honestly don't know wth your question even is. It's isn't clear at all in the post. [Look here](https://ideone.com/eUl0cx).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes thanks you very much it's work.

Comment: Prefer snprintf() to sprintf() to avoid table overflows. This contributes to the robustness of the programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Double2String(char *output,double val,int n)
{
    sprintf(output,"%0.*f", n, val); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7T3v38